# C++ overload operator +

Tags: c++, memory, overloading, destructor

I am trying to overload operator + for my class as follows:

```
MyClass MyClass::operator +(const MyClass& rval) const {
 MyClass ret(m_src); // m_src is member of MyClass: char* m_src;
 ret.Add(rval); // this->m_src + rval, this method work correctly 
 return ret; // so, in ret.m_src I have correct value
} // but after this C++ call destructor for ret
```

Destructor:

```
delete[] m_src; // because in some methods I allocate dynamic memory
```

So, destructor clear memory and function return trash. How I can avoid this situation? 
If I delete destructor, function work normal, but in this case I have memory leak :(

P.S: I can't change prototype of overloading +, unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about when you return from +?  You need to implement a copy constructor that does deep copying.

Comment: 1. This function is returning a `MyClass` , which is neither a reference or a pointer. 2. ret is not created with new constructor. Therefore, you don't need to `delete` it.

Comment: Yes, after return from +
Hm, I get to try it
May be exist more ways to solve my problem?

Comment: @KonfleDolex yes, and I'm not calling it. Destructor was called automatic after return from function.

Comment: can you post all of your constructors? i think there are more issues than just there.

Comment: @m0stwanted try returning a reference. Change the return type to `MyClass&` .

Comment: @thang Yes, I have only two constructors:
MyClass() : m_src(NULL), m_size(1) {}
MyClass(const char* src); // assign src to m_src

Comment: you need to make your copy constructor do deep copying.  otherwise, you have bigger problems.... you'll end up with tons of dangling pointers.

Comment: @KonfleDolex I try, but destructor was called anyway and it's doesn't worked.

Comment: changing the return type to MyClass& doesn't help.  Don't do it.  May cause problems down the road.  The stack object will get destroyed anyway.  If you leave it as it is, it may be elided out.  I don't know to what extent C++ is allowed to elide out stuff when you return a reference.

Comment: @m0stwanted sorry, what I said was wrong. Returning reference will not work. Try returning a pointer. Change the return type to `MyClass*` and change the function content to `MyClass* ret = new MyClass(m_src);ret.Add(*rval);return ret;`

Comment: @thang ok, I will try to make a copying constructor. Thank you

Comment: returning a class can be expensive. I would say returning a pointer is a better approach. BTW, you have to remember to `delete` the pointer returned.

Comment: @KonfleDolex I try it, but whether this will lead to a memory leak?

Comment: returning pointer changes the semantic of the + operator.  for example, if i want to do (a+b)+c...  if (a+b) returns a pointer, then (a+b)+c fails because there is no operator for + with pointer on the left.  with respect to returning a class, please see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: @m0stwanted as long as you `delete` the pointer returned, it will not cause memory leak. BTW, you can use software like `valgrind` to check for memory leak.

Comment: @m0stwanted forget what I have said. thang was right.

Comment: @thang you are right, if I change prototype with pointer, I can't write some of: MyClass sum = a + b; // a,b: MyClass

Comment: So, I write copying constructor, and return from operator like this: return (MyClass(ret)); Destructor calling anyway and I again have a trash in sum :(

Comment: So, in debugger first calling for ret, second - for copied variable ><

Comment: The semantics in this function are fine, the problem is somewhere else in your code. As you say, ret will be destructed, but not before it is copied to the destination of the caller.

Comment: But where can be mistake? All methods work fine, except this operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a copy constructor that copies `m_src`

```
MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& ref ) {
    m_src = new char[/*get len from ref*/];
    memcpy( m_src, ref.m_src, /* len from ref */ * sizeof(char) );
}
```

Now you can change the `operator+` to work with the copy constructor

```
MyClass MyClass::operator +(const MyClass& rval) const {
    MyClass ret(rval); // use copy constructor
    ret.Add(rval); // this->m_src + rval, this method work correctly 
    return ret; // so, in ret.m_src I have correct value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You avoid this by replacing:

```
char *m_src;
```

by:

```
std::string m_src;
```

in your class `MyClass`.

With `char *` as a class member what you get is easy to go mess up manual memory management, you simply replace that with implicit RAII based memory management of `std::string` and save yourself all those troubles. And this is the very purpose of existence of `std::string` in C++.

---

If you cannot use standard library `std::string` class(*though I simply fail to understand why*), You need to make sure you are following the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.

Comment: @m0stwanted You're using C++ but you can't use the C++ standard library? Do you know how silly that sounds? Is this some kind of homework question?

Comment: @m0stwanted: `std::string` is not STL. It is a C++ standard library class. It should be available for use with any Standard C++ compilant implementation.

Comment: std::string *can be* STL.  depends on whom you ask.

Comment: @Rapptz I know :) No, it is't a homework, but I need to make it without any library.

Comment: @m0stwanted: Well you are already using that very same library when you used any of the standard C++ constructs, So there is no additional library. It is one and the same library.You are just restricting yourself to not use a part of the standard library because of your wrong notion that it is a different library. It is not.